# flexible 2 column list layout

Tags: html, css, list, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very long list with two columns (bootstrap 3 col-3 and col-9 classes), which messes up below a certain viewport width. See here:

```
...<div class="modal-body">
            

            <ul id="supplylist" class="list-group row" >
                
<li class="list-group-item col-3">  A+R </li>   <li class="list-group-item col-9">  Valves & Fittings   </li>
<li class="list-group-item col-3">  ABB </li>   <li class="list-group-item col-9">  Automation,     Processing, Power   </li>
<li class="list-group-item col-3">  ABB Kent    </li>   <li class="list-group-item col-9">  Pneumatic Cylinders </li>
<li class="list-group-item col-3">  ABM Greifenberger   </li>   <li class="list-group-item col-9">  Motors & Geared Motors  </li>
<li class="list-group-item col-3">  ABS </li>   <li class="list-group-item col-9">  Pumps   </li>
<li class="list-group-item col-3">  ACE </li>   <li class="list-group-item col-9">  Shock Absorbers </li>
<li class="list-group-item col-3">  ADDA    </li>   <li class="list-group-item col-9">  Motors & Converters </li>
<li class="list-group-item col-3">  AEG </li>   <li class="list-group-item col-9">  Switchgear, Transformers, Motors    </li>
</ul>
</div>...
```

The problem is that a certain cell's content has more content than the width allows, so that it breaks, which messes up the layout. (see here: [Screenshot](http://centurius.de/Untitled.png)

I do not want the cells to collapse into a one-column design as I need the description of each brand next to it and not below it. If it is possible I would like the list to automatically adjust itself so that the height of the right column adjusts to the one on the left in case the left column has a text break inside of it. This is the case for the cell "ABM Greifenberger".

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any CSS that you've left out of this? When I pop your code into both Bootply and a Fiddle, it's just a column list of items, nothing is next to anything else at any viewport width... Honestly using a list to try and show things next to one another just seems odd/pointless/counterintuitive. Why not use a table, or divs?

Comment: @MattD is correct. This is not the way to use the list-group and column classes, they are not meant to be used this way. Basic, fundamental CSS says that if the lines are not equal heights, floated elements (the col-X-X) won't clear and gaps will occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list is a very poor way of doing this, as it's not meant to be structured this way. Each list item is supposed to come under another list item, not next to it.

I suggest using tables, which Bootstrap allows for quite nicely. Tables are meant to structure items next to one another, and Bootstrap has classes that make them fully responsive as well.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4f967kt1/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>A+R</td>
            <td>Valves & Fittings</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ABB</td>
            <td>Automation, Processing, Power</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ABB Kent</td>
            <td>Pneumatic Cylinders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ABM Greifenberger</td>
            <td>Motors & Geared Motors</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
td:first-child {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sometimes it is simple common sense. Table works absolutely great here, especially with the first child width style and table-striped class. Thanks for that!

Comment: No worries, development is always a learning process. Glad I could be of service. :)